# Creating new columns from the values of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe with different strings.

```
Additional Information  |  
IP=192.168.1.1, MAC ADDR=00:0a:95:9d:68:16, USER=kwfinn  
IP=192.168.0.1, MAC ADDR=00:0a:95:9d:68:17, USER=wattray  
Undefined System Error  
Specific groupname=CUSTGR1
IP=192.168.1.2, MAC ADDR=00:1B:44:11:3A:B7, USER=stwnck
```

What I want to do is to create new columns, IP Address and MAC Address with the corresponding values from the column above.

So that the expected output looks like this:

```
Additional Information                                  |IP Address  | MAC Address     |    
IP=192.168.1.1, MAC ADDR=00:0a:95:9d:68:16, USER=kwfinn |192.168.1.1 |00:0a:95:9d:68:16|  
IP=192.168.0.1, MAC ADDR=00:0a:95:9d:68:17, USER=wattray|192.168.0.1 |00:0a:95:9d:68:17|   
Undefined System Error                                  |            |                 |
Specific groupname=CUSTGR1                              |            |                 |  
IP=192.168.1.2, MAC ADDR=00:1B:44:11:3A:B7, USER=stwnck |192.168.1.2 |00:1B:44:11:3A:B7|
```

The problem is, that I cannot deal with the rows that does not contain IP and MAC. I tried splitting using np.where as well as finding partial matches but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is use list comprehension with filtering if not missing value or None and exist `,` and `=`, pass to `DataFrame` constructor and last use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
L = [dict(y.split("=") for y in v.split(", "))  
         if pd.notna(v) and ('=' in v) and (', ' in v)
         else {}
         for v in df['Additional Information']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index)
print (df1)
            IP           MAC ADDR     USER
0  192.168.1.1  00:0a:95:9d:68:16   kwfinn
1  192.168.0.1  00:0a:95:9d:68:17  wattray
2          NaN                NaN      NaN
3          NaN                NaN      NaN
4  192.168.1.2  00:1B:44:11:3A:B7   stwnck

df = df.join(df1[['IP','MAC ADDR']])
print (df)
                              Additional Information           IP  \
0  IP=192.168.1.1, MAC ADDR=00:0a:95:9d:68:16, US...  192.168.1.1   
1  IP=192.168.0.1, MAC ADDR=00:0a:95:9d:68:17, US...  192.168.0.1   
2                           Undefined System Error            NaN   
3                         Specific groupname=CUSTGR1          NaN   
4  IP=192.168.1.2, MAC ADDR=00:1B:44:11:3A:B7, US...  192.168.1.2   

            MAC ADDR  
0  00:0a:95:9d:68:16  
1  00:0a:95:9d:68:17  
2                NaN  
3                NaN  
4  00:1B:44:11:3A:B7
```

Comment: Like your solution. But for some reason I got an error "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required" on the if statement row.

Comment: @aur.serv - how working if change `[dict(y.split("=") for y in v.split(", "))  
         if ('=' in v) and (', ' in v)
         else {}
         for k, v in df['Additional Information'].items() ]` to `[dict(y.split("=") for y in v.split(","))  
         if ('=' in v) and (',' in v)
         else {}
         for k, v in df['Additional Information'].items() ]` ? 2 times changed `', '` to `','`

Comment: throws argument of type 'float' is not iterable error

Comment: @aur.serv - Can you check `L = [dict(y.split("=") for y in v.split(","))  
         if pd.notna(v) and ('=' in v) and (',' in v)
         else {}
         for v in df['Additional Information']]` ?